# move caret to end of textarea on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I thought this would be quite a simple thing to do but I can't get it to work. I am using the following code but with no success. I know this does not work in ie, I am using chrome. here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xaxz53x/) to demonstrate. Thanks

```
$('#ta').focus(function(){
  this.selectionStart = this.value.length;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you wanted to see how to fix you original solution so that it may work, here is what you had to do:

```
$('#ta').focus(function (e) {
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        element.selectionStart = element.value.length;
    }, 1);
});
```

The position must be set after a very short delay (1 millisecond is sufficient in my case) because it seems as though the cursors position is set to where you click *after* the focus function is finished, so you are setting the cursor to be at the end of the input but then it is immediately being placed where the user clicked right after this happens

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zb5uoL3t/

Comment: thanks, I realized this a little too late, when in doubt, add timeOut :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a cross-browser and jQuery compliant solution (it supports multiple elements in a given selector).

Tested in Chrome 40x, IE 11, and FireFox 34x

```js
$("textarea").focus(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).length; i++) {
        var el = $(this)[i]
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            if (el !== null) {
                if (el.createTextRange) {
                    var range = el.createTextRange();
                    range.move('character', el.value.length);
                    range.select();
                }
                else {
                    if (el.selectionStart || el.selectionStart === 0) {
                        el.focus();
                        el.setSelectionRange(el.value.length, el.value.length);
                    }
                    else {
                        el.focus();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 1)
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ta">focus on me</textarea><br />
<textarea id="ta2">focus on me</textarea>
```

Comment: @briansol - that's what I get for copy/pasting... fixed.

Comment: nice code, but doesn't  work if focused by tabbing +1

Comment: @user2014429 Change .click to .focus? I suppose you'd also have to create some sort of flag to stop the function from running if you focus programmatically to prevent an infinite loop

Comment: @user2014429 - good catch, didn't think about that scenario.  I'll update it as soon as I get a chance.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2014429 - code has been updated to include tabbing into the field.  Thanks again for catching this!

Answer (score -1):

a quick one

```
$('#ta').focus(function(){
    moveCursorToEnd(document.getElementById('ta'));
});

function moveCursorToEnd(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9xaxz53x/1/